# How to get date as out of ek.get_data together with value in Refinitiv Eikon?

Tags: refinitiv-eikon-api, refinitiv-eikon

I am trying to retrieve historical Book Value per Share using the Refinitiv Eikon API. Apart from the value, I would also like to output the date corresponding to the value.

I am currently able to output the values:

```
import eikon as ek
ek.set_app_key(my_api)

ric = 'MSFT.O'

params = {'SDate':'1999-12-31',
          'EDate' :'2021-03-01',
          'Period': 'FQ0',
          'Frq':'FQ',
          'reportingState':'Rsdt',
          'curn':'Native',
          'Scale':'3'}

df = ek.get_data(ric, 'TR.BookValuePerShare', parameters=params)
```

This will output the time-series but it will be indexed by integers.

I can use the Data Item Browser to see that in the parameters I could specify output Date as well as Value.[image: Data Item Browser] to

However, if I simply try:

```
params = {'SDate':'1999-12-31',
          'EDate' :'2021-03-01',
          'Period': 'FQ0',
          'Frq':'FQ',
          'reportingState':'Rsdt',
          'curn':'Native',
          'Scale':'3', 
          'Output': 'Date',
   
}
```

This will give me an error message:

```
(        0  TR.BOOKVALUEPERSHARE
 0  MSFT.O                  <NA>,
 [{'code': 405,
   'col': 1,
   'message': "Invalid output format: neither 'Col' nor 'Row' parameter is specified before output colums/rows.",
   'row': 0}])
```

What are these Row and Col objects? How can I output other fields as well as value?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This can be done with a seperate RIC attribute, as follows:

```
df = ek.get_data(ric, ['TR.BookValuePerShare', 'TR.BookValuePerShare.dates'], parameters=params)
```